# JQuery Promise: fail() called without waiting for promise to resolve

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, xmlhttprequest, promise

I have the following jQuery promise (using TypeScript). Strangely, the action in fail() is called straight away - the error message is written to the console - even though the promise then resolves successfully:

```js
            this.jQuery.getJSON(this.options.searchUrl, queryFilter)
                       .done(this.orderLinesCallback)
                       .fail(console.log("Error on retrieving orders"));
```

Comment: How do you can ensure that promise was resolved successfully?

Comment: try `.fail( function(){ console.log("Error on retrieving orders") } )`. you actually execute `console.log()` and use the return value (`undefined`) as a callback for `fail()`.

Comment: Always the obvious gets overlooked. @Sirko is correct. You are simply always running `console` as it is not in an anonymous function :)

Comment: Another thing: the callback to the `done()` function will lose its scope. You may want to add `.bind( this )` to it, if the scope is necessary.

Comment: My bad. Yes, done() was calling a function but fail() wasn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`done` and `fail` argument must be a function :

```
.done(this.orderLinesCallback)
.fail(function(e, f, g) {
    console.log("Error on retrieving orders");
});
```

Doing like this garantee that `console.log("Error on retrieving orders");` is executed only when the anonymous function (argument of `fail`) is called